# Question about BSc in preparation for research career closed as "undergrad" question?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic-ness, undergraduate

This question asks about qualities to consider in an undergrad degree, in order to get into AI research in the future:

[What factors are important in an online BSc for eventual goal of AI research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29833/what-factors-are-important-in-an-online-bsc-for-eventual-goal-of-ai-research)

It was closed as an "undergrad" question.

However, as far as I can tell, it seems to be about preparation for entry into a research field. It's not any different from questions asking about undergraduate degrees in preparation for graduate admissions (which are firmly on-topic here). It just looks a couple of steps farther, i.e. getting into research vs. getting into graduate school.

If "Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher" is [explicitly on-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it's not clear to me why "Transitioning from undergraduate to researcher" is off-topic.

Is this kind of question really an "undergrad" question? If so, why?

Comment: We unfortunately have some users who, as soon as they see anything related to undergraduate studies, vote to close without looking further. I think this question is off-topic, because, as you wrote it, it's more about giving recommendation, not because it's an undergrad question.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset My comments about shopping are obsolete (now deleted) since the latest edits to the question; it's no longer asking us to recommend a program. As far as I can tell, it's now about what factors to consider in choosing a degree program, which seems on-topic to me.

Comment: It's quite related to AI. If we take that question, do we need to have one for each specialisation of each field?

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Per [this meta post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/is-what-background-do-i-need-to-do-research-in-specific-field-x-on-topic-at-a), it seems that the community considers questions like these to be academia questions, not domain-specific questions, so yes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've down-voted your answer there, since I believe such questions should *not* be on-topic :) Also, as a general rule, I wouldn't consider few up-votes as meaning " the community considers questions like these to be academia questions", but rather "nobody was really against it". If you have less votes on a meta answer than what is required to close a question, then I'd say let the community decide case-by-case.